# What's this button for displaying/hiding a sidebar called?

Tags: terminology

Some applications/websites have a sidebar which appears on clicking a button, and disappears on clicking (a modified version of) that button. For example, Atom (text editor):

[image]

[image]

What is this type of button called?

Comment: ermm.... a "button"... or maybe "toggle button" .... what makes you think it has a *specific* name?

Comment: In the html in your screenshot it seems to be called a "sidebar button" which I think is a fitting name.

Comment: @Wolff - this is one of those "it's right in front of your nose" moments.  LOL

Comment: @Wolff Actually, I myself called it a 'sidebar-button'. Some things do have specific names (like a hamburger menu), so I thought maybe I should ask about the right terminology if there is one. Thanks though.

Comment: @Scott Thank you for telling me this. This answers my question. I thought maybe it might have a specific name.